# Malformed access token 190 error

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

when trying to redirect to gain a new access token an error occurred saying :

```
(OAuthException - #190) Malformed access token AQClEC8NbS1tbO4_HzqqZwVy2Inrk5I7vBpszPDPN0dVOV0ekurwNEpqzlWe2hQzl2KNZ5BwiSvL16bDPhR5IxFeJXEXBdM67uky7iwKbYKIVoRF__iyayyXBgcIp939gEZNtCUxyO4ZKZHQ9xmEwDstaOgq_bAvtygwv3YUeEYD9wftsytMZYwVxDO7rjq-2i3-XCYj643-6_1yKZ0dDahAB00iBqJqw1xiZ-l1kzStmA_pwMwO5dtBHZozp-L2hp0JEeTL0Fhc5CG1zbJ8Om6kyKBWyZuc0AtOrdSjgcBQBv9hQSF5pwsMZvFDGcjiwSc
```

what possibly could be the problem i am doing this method to redirect :

```
string redirecturl = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=507061112747022&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx";
    Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
```

and i am reading the access token as follow :

```
string accessToken=Request["code"];
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken); // here is where the error occurred
```

1. Is this the right method to get a client access token ?
2. why this error is occurring when reading the `code` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to Facebook Debug tool, your `token` is not a Token but a URL instead: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=AQClEC8NbS1tbO4_HzqqZwVy2Inrk5I7vBpszPDPN0dVOV0ekurwNEpqzlWe2hQzl2KNZ5BwiSvL16bDPhR5IxFeJXEXBdM67uky7iwKbYKIVoRF__iyayyXBgcIp939gEZNtCUxyO4ZKZHQ9xmEwDstaOgq_bAvtygwv3YUeEYD9wftsytMZYwVxDO7rjq

I'm not sure who you get it, and why you get it instead of access token - you did not show enough code. From what I saw, I believe you generate your `redirecturl` incorrectly. Below is a piece of code from one of my project - please try it and let me know if it works for you:

```
// 1. redirect user to the login page:
var redirectUri = "http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx";

var service = new FacebookClient();
var loginUrl = service.GetLoginUrl(new {
    client_id = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppId,
    client_secret = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppSecret,
    redirect_uri = redirectUri,
    response_type = "code",
    scope = "manage_pages, publish_actions, user_photos, publish_stream" // Add other permissions as needed
});

Response.Redirect(loginUrl);

// 2. And when user authorizes, get the access token
// NOTE: code executes on FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx page
var redirectUri = "http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx";  // must be the same as in the login call!
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppId,
    client_secret = ConfigurationProvider.FacebookAppSecret,
    redirect_uri = redirectUri,
    code = code
});

var accessToken = result.access_token;
```